# How to prove this special case of the Fundamental Lemma of calculus of variations?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus-of-variations

> Consider an interval $I = [t_0,t_1]$ and a finite dimensional Banach space $X$. Let further be $\mathcal{C}_0^1(I,X)$ be the set of $\mathcal{C}^1$ functions vanishing on the boundary. Show the following special case of the Fundamental Lemma of calculus of variations:
>
> If a continuous $x^\ast: I \rightarrow X^\ast$ has the property $\int_I x(t)^\ast (x(t)) dt = 0$ for all $x \in \mathcal{C}_0^1(I,X)$, then $x^\ast(t) = 0$.
>
> Remark: $X^\ast$ denotes the dual space of $X$.

I do not see how to prove this. Could you please give me a hint?

Edit:

I recognsie that by the Riesz Representation Theorem we may find a $y \in X$ such that $\langle y, \cdot \rangle = x^\ast (\cdot)$ that $\langle y,x \rangle =x(t)^\ast(x(t))$. We note that for any $x \in \mathcal{C}_0^1$ we got:

\begin{align}
0 &= \int_I \langle y(t),x(t)y(t) \rangle dt \\
&= \int_I x(t) \langle y(t),y(t) \rangle\\
\text{Using integration by parts yields:}\\
&= \bigg( x(t) \int_I \langle y(t),y(t) \rangle dt \bigg) \bigg\rvert_{t_0}^{t_1}   - \int_I x^\prime(t) \langle y(t),y(t) \rangle dt
\end{align}

I see that $\bigg( x(t) \int_I \langle y(t),y(t) \rangle dt \bigg) \bigg\rvert_{t_0}^{t_1} = 0$, but I do not get how to go on from here.

Comment: Maybe take a scalarproduct $<\ ,\ >$ on $X$, that allows you to turn your map $x^*:I\rightarrow X^*$ into a map $y:I\rightarrow X$, such that $x(t)(v)=<y(t),v>$ for all $v\in V$.

Comment: Thanks for your hint, I edited my question.

Comment: You dont have double integral, you just have to integrate the function $t\mapsto <y(t),x(t)>$ on the interval $I$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get it. I do not see how to integrate $\langle y(t),x(t) \rangle$. I realise that we may pull the integral inside the sclaraproduct, so we may write $\int_I \langle y(t),x(t) \rangle dt = \langle y(t), \int_I x(t) dt \rangle$. But what does this help?

Comment: Thats not true that you can put the integration inside the scalar product. If you choose an orthonormal basis in $X$, then $x(t)=(x_1(t),\dots,x_n(t))$, $y(t)=(y_1(t),\dots,y_n(t))$, where all $x_i$ and $y_j$ are continuous functions from $I$ to $\mathbb{R}$. Now the function you have to integrate is $\sum_{i=1}^n y_i(t)x_i(t)$. I hope this shows that you cant just put inside the integration into the scalar product, Now suppose you have a continuous function $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, with $0\leq f$, and $f(0)=f(1)=0$. Then what can you say about the function $<x(t),f(t)x(t)>$?

Comment: I am not sure what you allue to, but we may write $\langle x(t), f(t)x(t) \rangle = f(t) \langle x(t), x(t) \rangle$.

Comment: and what do you know about $<x(t),x(t)>$?

Comment: I know that by the definition of sclara product $\langle x , x \rangle = 0$ iff $x = 0$. And that $\lvert\lvert x \lvert\lvert = \sqrt{\langle x , x \rangle}$. However, I do not see the connection to the exercise. I do not get where the $f$ in $\langle x(t) , f(t)x(t) \rangle$ comes from.

Comment: Yes, also notice that $f(0)x(0)=f(1)x(1)=0$ by the assumption on $f$. Thus you know that the integral $\int_I <x(t),f(t)x(t)>dt=0$, for all $f:I\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ that is continuous and $f(0)=f(1)=0$.

Comment: Sorry, but I can not follow you. I do not get where the $f$ in $\langle x(t),f(t)x(t) \rangle$ comes from.

Comment: Sorry I accidentaly mixed up $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ in the last three comments. Well you want to show that $y(t)$ is zero for all $t$. Now suppose that $\int_I <y(t),y(t)>dt=0$, then you can conclude that $y(t)=0$ for all $t$ (otherwise the integral would be strictly positive). Now this argument fails because we cant guarantee that $\int_I <y(t),y(t)>dt=0$, but thats where $f$ comes in play. By multiplying with $f$ you get a continuous function $f(t)y(t):I\rightarrow X$, which is zero in $0$ and $1$ and now you can use assumption that $\int <y(t),f(t)y(t)> dt=0$. Can you finish from here?

Comment: No sorry, I edited my question again.

Comment: To finish let's assume that there exists a $t_0$ such that $y(t_0)\neq 0$, then by continuity we know that for $\varepsilon$ small enough $y(t)\neq 0$ for all $t\in [t_0-\varepsilon,t_0+\varepsilon]=D_{t_o}(\varepsilon)$ (also we can assume that $t_0\neq 0$ and $t_0\neq 1$). Now pick a continuous function $f$ such that  $f(t)=1$ for all $t\in D_{t_0}(\varepsilon/2)$, and such that $f$ is zere outside of $D_{t_0}(\varepsilon)$. Now we get that $0=\int_I <y(t),f(t)y(t)>dt\geq \int_{D_{t_o}}f(t)<y(t),y(t)>dt > 0$ which is a  contradiction.